# meaning of the phrase "play humans"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Some dogs were skilled at finding and snatching food and avoiding dogcatchers, unfriendly dogs, and people. Some were good at “**playing” humans** for food, whereas others weren’t.

Does that mean that when dogs want to get food, they try to imitate humans?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your question title says *playing human*, but the quote says *playing humans*.  These are two very different things, and this is the source of your confusion.

*Play human* would mean 'pretend to be human; imitate a human' as you've suggested above.  But that isn't what this example says.  You should be able to find this meaning in dictionaries readily.

*Play humans*, on the other hand, means 'manipulate humans to get what they want'.  This meaning is a little tricky to find in dictionaries since it's a bit slangy, and that's probably why it was put in quotes, but it's related to the meaning *play (someone) for a fool* which you should be able to find:

> **play someone for** *Treat someone as being of (a specified type)*.
>   ‘don't imagine you can play me for a fool’
>
> ([Source: The Oxford Dictionary of English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/play))

The slang version of the word can be used without a *for*-phrase as a complement.

Comment: I am sorry I made a typo. I was exactly confused by "play humans".

Comment: +1 but what you've written is a little misleading: "playing humans" _could_ also mean imitating humans.  The "manipulate" meaning just makes a lot more sense in this context.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point.  I should probably have drawn a three-way distinction in this answer.

Comment: The sense ‘manipulate’ may be related to the metaphor of a musical instrument: one occasionally hears “She played you like a violin.”